# Variables not updating from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently working on a profile page for my website. It is all going along pretty well so far, except on the edit profile page. The database does not seem to be updating the variables like it should be, and I have no clue why. There are 3 main blocks of code, and the actual input part is the issue I think.

Before that the variables are not updated, but after that block of code the variables are update (it is a form). By the way, if you want to know what the issue is, here it is. If a user inputs something, but then deletes it, it re-inputs the data on the form submit. Now, here are the 3 main blocks of code (in order):

## Startup

```
function utf8_encode_string($value) {
    if (empty($_POST[$value])) {
        $str = "";
        return $str;
    }
    else {
        $str = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST[$value]), ENT_QUOTES));
        return $str;
    }
}

//Grabs all of the profile information
$accountinfoquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$accountinfoparams = array(':username' => $accounturl);

try{
    $accountinfostmt = $connection->prepare($accountinfoquery);
    $accountinforesult = $accountinfostmt->execute($accountinfoparams);
}

catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$accountinfocolumns = $accountinfostmt->fetch();

$firstnameinput = utf8_encode_string("firstname");
$lastnameinput = utf8_encode_string("lastname");
$ageinput = utf8_encode_string("age");
$locationinput = utf8_encode_string("location");
$quoteinput = utf8_encode_string("quote");
$genderinput = utf8_encode_string("gender");
$aboutinput = utf8_encode_string("about");

if (!$firstnameinput) {
    $firstnameinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["firstname"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$lastnameinput) {
    $lastnameinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["lastname"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$ageinput) {
    if ($accountinfocolumns["age"] == "0") {
        $ageinput = "";
    }
    else {
        $ageinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["age"]), ENT_QUOTES));
    }
}

if (!$locationinput) {
    $locationinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["location"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$quoteinput) {
    $quoteinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["quote"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$genderinput) {
    $genderinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["gender"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$aboutinput) {
    $aboutinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["about"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

//Final Check
$firstnamefinalcheck = False;
$lastnamefinalcheck = False;
$agefinalcheck = False;
$locationfinalcheck = False;
$quotefinalcheck = False;
$aboutfinalcheck = False;
```

## Inputs

(IMPORTANT: I think the issue is near the button).

```
<form action="http://localhost/postin'/profiles/edit/<?php print utf8_decode($loggedin_session_permalink); ?>" method="post">

<div class="row" id="informationquoteholder">
    <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
        Quote
    </div>

<div id="quoteinputwidth" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-8">
    <input type="text" name="quote" id="quoteinput" value="<?php print utf8_decode($quoteinput); ?>" />
</div>
<?php
    if ($_POST) {
        $quotetest1 = False;
        $quotetest2 = False;

            if (utf8_decode(trim($_POST["quote"])) == "") {
                $quotefinalcheck = True;
                $quoteinput = "";
            }

            else {
                // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($quoteinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is too short. </div>
<?php
                }

                elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($quoteinput), "UTF-8") > 100 ) {
?>
                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is too long, maxium 100 characters.</div>
<?php
                }

                else {
                    $quotetest1 = True;

                    // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                    if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N},() _@.?!:;-]+$~u", utf8_decode($quoteinput))) {
?>
                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                    }

                    elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){10,}~mui', utf8_decode($quoteinput))) {
?>
                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is not valid. </div>
<?php
                    }

                    else {
                        $quotetest2 = True;

                        // Final Check

                        if (($quotetest1) and ($quotetest2)) {
                            $quotefinalcheck = True;
                            $quoteinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["quote"]), ENT_QUOTES));
                        }

                        else {
                            $quotefinalcheck = False;
?>
                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <button id="profileinformationbutton" input type="submit" value="Login"> Update Profile </button>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="http://localhost/postin'/profiles/<?php print utf8_decode($loggedin_session_permalink); ?>">
        <div id="informationcancelbutton" input type="submit" value="Cancel"> Cancel </div>
    </a>
</div>

</form>
```

## Database update

```
<?php

        if ($quotefinalcheck) {

            $quote_for_database = "";
            if (isset($quoteinput)) {
                $quote_for_database = $quoteinput;
            }
            else {
                $quote_for_database = "";
            }

            $inputquery = "UPDATE users SET quote = :quote, WHERE id = :id";
            $datasend = $connection->prepare($inputquery);
            $datasend->execute(array(':quote'=>utf8_decode($quote_for_database),
                                     ':id'=>$_SESSION["logged_in"]));
        }

?>
```

I think the main issue is just the order of the way I am doing this. If you want the full code here it is (Please note, some parts are for different things):

```
<?php

require("C:\wamp\www\postin'\db_connection.php");

//Grabs the URL
$urlname = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$urlquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE permalink = :permalink";
$urlparams = array(':permalink' => $urlname[4]);

try{
    $urlstmt = $connection->prepare($urlquery);
    $urlresult = $urlstmt->execute($urlparams);
}

catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$urlcolumns = $urlstmt->fetch();
$accounturl = $urlcolumns["username"];

if(!$urlcolumns){
    header("Location: http://localhost/postin'/home.php");
    exit();
}

else {

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\head.php");?>
    <title> POSTIN' Profile <?php echo $accounturl; ?> </title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/postin'/css/style.profile.php.css"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/postin'/css/style.editprofile.php.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="wrapper" class="container">

<?php

//Stars the sessions
session_start();

//Makes sure the user is trying to edit there profile
if (!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {                                                   
    header("Location: http://localhost/postin'/home.php");
    exit();
}

$sessionquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id";

$sessionparams = array(':id' => $_SESSION["logged_in"]);

try{
    $sessionstmt = $connection->prepare($sessionquery);
    $sessionresult = $sessionstmt->execute($sessionparams);
}

catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$sessionfetch = $sessionstmt->fetch();

$loggedin_session_username = $sessionfetch["username"];

if($accounturl != $loggedin_session_username){
    header("Location: http://localhost/postin'/home.php");
    exit();
}

else {

//Adds the header and sidebar
include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\header.php");
include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\sidebar.php");

//Sets the "last_url" to this page
if (!isset($_SESSION["last_url"])) {
    $_SESSION["last_url"] = "http://localhost/postin'/home.php";
}
$last_url = $_SESSION["last_url"];

//Grabs all of the profile information
$accountinfoquery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

$accountinfoparams = array(':username' => $accounturl);

try{
    $accountinfostmt = $connection->prepare($accountinfoquery);
    $accountinforesult = $accountinfostmt->execute($accountinfoparams);
}

catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo ("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}

$accountinfocolumns = $accountinfostmt->fetch();

$firstnameinput = utf8_encode_string("firstname");
$lastnameinput = utf8_encode_string("lastname");
$ageinput = utf8_encode_string("age");
$locationinput = utf8_encode_string("location");
$quoteinput = utf8_encode_string("quote");
$genderinput = utf8_encode_string("gender");
$aboutinput = utf8_encode_string("about");

if (!$firstnameinput) {
    $firstnameinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["firstname"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$lastnameinput) {
    $lastnameinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["lastname"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$ageinput) {
    if ($accountinfocolumns["age"] == "0") {
        $ageinput = "";
    }
    else {
        $ageinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["age"]), ENT_QUOTES));
    }
}

if (!$locationinput) {
    $locationinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["location"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$quoteinput) {
    $quoteinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["quote"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$genderinput) {
    $genderinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["gender"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

if (!$aboutinput) {
    $aboutinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($accountinfocolumns["about"]), ENT_QUOTES));
}

//Final Check
$firstnamefinalcheck = False;
$lastnamefinalcheck = False;
$agefinalcheck = False;
$locationfinalcheck = False;
$quotefinalcheck = False;
$aboutfinalcheck = False;
?>

        <div id="mobilephonescrollplace">
            Hold Here To Slide Screen
        </div>

        <div class="maincontentssection">


<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->
<!-- WHERE THE USER CHANGES HIS PROFILE INFORMATION -->
<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->

            <div id="accountinformationholder" class="row">

                <div id="picturequoteholder" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="accountpictureholder" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12 margintopimageeditpage">
                            <div id="accountpictureview">
                                <img src="http://localhost/postin'/images/logo.png" id="accountpictureholderspecs">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="changepictureholder" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-12">
                            <div id="changepicture">
                                Change Picture
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="editinformationholder" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-8">
                    <form action="http://localhost/postin'/profiles/edit/<?php print utf8_decode($loggedin_session_permalink); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div id="importantinformation" class="col-xs-12">
                                    (*) means field is required.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                                        * First Name
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="informationfirstname" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstnameinput" value="<?php print mb_ucfirst($firstnameinput); ?>" />
                                    </div>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $firstnametest1 = False;
                                    $firstnametest2 = False;

                                    // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                    if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($firstnameinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> First name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                    }

                                    elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($firstnameinput), "UTF-8") > 25 ) {
?>
                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> First name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        $firstnametest1 = True;

                                        // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                        if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}]+$~u", utf8_decode($firstnameinput))) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> First name contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){10,}~mui', utf8_decode($firstnameinput))) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> First name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $firstnametest2 = True;

                                            // Final Check

                                            if (($firstnametest1) and ($firstnametest2)) {
                                                $firstnamefinalcheck = True;
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $firstnamefinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                                        * Last Name
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="informationlastname" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastnameinput" value="<?php print mb_ucfirst($lastnameinput); ?>" />
                                    </div>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $lastnametest1 = False;
                                    $lastnametest2 = False;

                                    // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                    if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($lastnameinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Last name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                    }

                                    elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($lastnameinput), "UTF-8") > 35 ) {
?>
                                        <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Last name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        $lastnametest1 = True;

                                        // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                        if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N}-]+$~u", utf8_decode($lastnameinput))) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Last name contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){10,}~mui', utf8_decode($lastnameinput))) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Last name is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $lastnametest2 = True;

                                            // Final Check

                                            if (($lastnametest1) and ($lastnametest2)) {
                                                $lastnamefinalcheck = True;
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $lastnamefinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                                        Age
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="informationage" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" name="age" id="ageinput" value="<?php print utf8_decode($ageinput); ?>" />
                                    </div>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $agetest1 = False;
                                    $agetest2 = False;

                                    if (utf8_decode(trim($_POST["age"])) == "") {
                                        $agefinalcheck = True;
                                        $ageinput = "";
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                        if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($ageinput), "UTF-8") > 3 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Age is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(utf8_decode($ageinput) > 125 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Age is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(utf8_decode($ageinput) < 14 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> You are too young. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $agetest1 = True;

                                            // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                            if(!preg_match("~^[0-9]+$~", utf8_decode($ageinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Age is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $agetest2 = True;

                                                // Final Check

                                                if (($agetest1) and ($agetest2)) {
                                                    $agefinalcheck = True;
                                                    $ageinput = $_POST["age"];
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    $agefinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                                </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                    <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
                                        Location
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="informationlocation" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7">
                                        <input type="text" name="location" id="locationinput" value="<?php print utf8_decode($locationinput); ?>" />
                                    </div>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $locationtest1 = False;
                                    $locationtest2 = False;

                                    if (utf8_decode(trim($_POST["location"])) == "") {
                                        $locationfinalcheck = True;
                                        $locationinput = "";
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                        if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($locationinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Location is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($locationinput), "UTF-8") > 60 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Location is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $locationtest1 = True;

                                            // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                            if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N},() .-]+$~u", utf8_decode($locationinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Location contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){10,}~mui', utf8_decode($locationinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Location is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $locationtest2 = True;

                                                // Final Check

                                                if (($locationtest1) and ($locationtest2)) {
                                                    $locationfinalcheck = True;
                                                    $locationinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["location"]), ENT_QUOTES));
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    $locationfinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                <div id="informationtiptext">
                                    <strong>Remember:</strong> Anyone can see your profile, do not share information you do not want others to know!
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="informationquoteholder">
                            <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                Quote
                            </div>

                            <div id="quoteinputwidth" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5 col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" name="quote" id="quoteinput" value="<?php print utf8_decode($quoteinput); ?>" />
                            </div>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $quotetest1 = False;
                                    $quotetest2 = False;

                                    if (utf8_decode(trim($_POST["quote"])) == "") {
                                        $quotefinalcheck = True;
                                        $quoteinput = "";
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                        if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($quoteinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is too short. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($quoteinput), "UTF-8") > 100 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is too long, maxium 100 characters.</div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $quotetest1 = True;

                                            // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                            if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N},() _@.?!:;-]+$~u", utf8_decode($quoteinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){10,}~mui', utf8_decode($quoteinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> Quote is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $quotetest2 = True;

                                                // Final Check

                                                if (($quotetest1) and ($quotetest2)) {
                                                    $quotefinalcheck = True;
                                                    $quoteinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["quote"]), ENT_QUOTES));
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    $quotefinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                    <div id="allinputboxerror" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="informationgenderholder">
                            <div id="informationtitlesmall" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                Gender
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" id="radioholder" >
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="selectormale" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> <!-- Gender Selector -->
                                    <label for="selectormale"> Male </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="selectorfemale" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="selectorfemale"> Female </label>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Other" id="selectorother" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                                    <label for="selectorother"> Other </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row" id="aboutinformationeditboxholder">
                            <div id="informationtitlesmallabout" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                                About
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" id="aboutinformationeditbox">
                                <textarea id="aboutinformationboxstyle" rows="1" cols="15" name="about" maxlength="10000"><?php print utf8_decode($aboutinput); ?></textarea>
                                <div id="aboutcharactercount"> <span id="textareacharactercount">0</span> / 2500 </div>
                                <script>
                                    function wordCount(val){
                                        return {characters : val.length,};
                                    }

                                    var print = document.getElementById("textareacharactercount");
                                    var grab = document.getElementById("aboutinformationboxstyle");

                                    grab.addEventListener("input", function(){
                                        var wordcountprint = wordCount( this.value );
                                        print.innerHTML = (wordcountprint.characters);
                                    }, false);
                                </script>
<?php
                                if ($_POST) {
                                    $abouttest1 = False;
                                    $abouttest2 = False;

                                    if (utf8_decode(trim($_POST["about"])) == "") {
                                        $aboutfinalcheck = True;
                                        $aboutinput = "";
                                    }

                                    else {
                                        // Test #1 - Makes sure it fits the length requirements

                                        if(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($aboutinput), "UTF-8") < 3 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerroraboutbox" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"> About section is too short. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        elseif(mb_strlen(utf8_decode($aboutinput), "UTF-8") > 2500 ) {
?>
                                            <div id="allinputboxerroraboutbox" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"> About section is too long. </div>
<?php
                                        }

                                        else {
                                            $abouttest1 = True;

                                            // Test #2 - Makes sure it does not have any restricted characters

                                            if(!preg_match("~^[\p{L}\p{N},() _@.?!:;\r\n-]+$~u", utf8_decode($aboutinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerroraboutbox" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"> About section contains restricted characters. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            elseif(preg_match('~(\S)(?:\1){50,}~mui', utf8_decode($aboutinput))) {
?>
                                                <div id="allinputboxerroraboutbox" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"> About section is not valid. </div>
<?php
                                            }

                                            else {
                                                $abouttest2 = True;

                                                // Final Check

                                                if (($abouttest1) and ($abouttest2)) {
                                                    $aboutfinalcheck = True;
                                                    $aboutinput = utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST["about"]), ENT_QUOTES));
                                                }

                                                else {
                                                    $aboutfinalcheck = False;
?>
                                                    <div id="allinputboxerroraboutbox" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7"> There is a error. </div>
<?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
?>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button id="profileinformationbutton" input type="submit" value="Login"> Update Profile </button>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <a href="http://localhost/postin'/profiles/<?php print utf8_decode($loggedin_session_permalink); ?>">
                                <div id="informationcancelbutton" input type="submit" value="Cancel"> Cancel </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->
<!-- AN AD -->
<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->

<!-- BELOW WILL BE EXECUTED IF THE USER HAS ALLOWED ADS IN THERE PREFERENCES -->
<!-- DISPLAYS THE ADS -->

<?php
            if (isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {
                if ($loggedin_session_allowads == "false") {

                }

                else {
?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\ads\adleaderboard1.php");?>
                </div>
<?php
                }
            }

            else {
?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\ads\adleaderboard1.php");?>
                </div>
<?php
            }
?>

<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->
<!-- UPDATES THE DATABASE -->
<!-- ========================================================================================================================== -->

<?php

    if (($firstnamefinalcheck) and ($lastnamefinalcheck) and ($agefinalcheck) and ($locationfinalcheck) and ($quotefinalcheck)) {
        $age_for_database = "";
        if (isset($ageinput)) {
            $age_for_database = $ageinput;
        }
        else {
            $age_for_database = "";
        }

        $location_for_database = "";
        if (isset($locationinput)) {
            $location_for_database = $locationinput;
        }
        else {
            $location_for_database = "";
        }

        $quote_for_database = "";
        if (isset($quoteinput)) {
            $quote_for_database = $quoteinput;
        }
        else {
            $quote_for_database = "";
        }

        $about_for_database = "";
        if (isset($aboutinput)) {
            $about_for_database = $aboutinput;
        }
        else {
            $about_for_database = "";
        }

        $inputquery = "UPDATE users SET firstname = :firstname, lastname = :lastname, age = :age, location = :location, quote = :quote, gender = :gender, about = :about WHERE id = :id";
        $datasend = $connection->prepare($inputquery);
        $datasend->execute(array(':firstname'=>mb_ucfirst($firstnameinput),
                                 ':lastname'=>mb_ucfirst($lastnameinput),
                                 ':age'=>utf8_decode($age_for_database),
                                 ':location'=>utf8_decode($location_for_database),
                                 ':quote'=>utf8_decode($quote_for_database),
                                 ':gender'=>$genderinput,
                                 ':about'=>utf8_decode($about_for_database), 
                                 ':id'=>$_SESSION["logged_in"]));
    }

?>

        </div>

        <?php include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\bottom.php");?>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

<?php }} ?>
```

Comment: what type of local server are you using now?

Comment: Nice code but what about OOP?

Comment: Well, first I am designing the website (It is going to be a open forum type website where users can post about whatever they would like), and I am 14 working on it by myself. So I am first just trying to get it done, then once it is all done and open to the public I will go back to every page and redo it with OOP, and make them better! :)

Comment: sorry to ask again. can you connect the database with PDO connection in this localhost?

Comment: Yes, I connect to the database with PDO, but that is really the only PDO I use. Eventually later once the website is done, and I use more OOP, I will use OOP and PDO a lot! :)

Comment: Add `$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Debugging is the first part you should learn while coding, before posting a question.

Comment: Nope, no errors reported :) So I was also doing some more testing, and right before the form starts it has the old database value. Then after the form it has the new value. For some reason it just does not want to update from the database. I asked my brother (went to college for CS), and he said the order was most likely off (too busy to ever help though :(.

Comment: @Jean Gkol, any idea on why this might not be working? I have been trying everything, and still no luck :9

Comment: @michaeljones, pls see my answer. I really hope it helps you. sorry for being late since my internet connection got crash in 12 hours :(

Comment: You seem to be trying to do the right thing here, but what a jumble of code this is. Modern PHP development encourages the use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that gives you a solid foundation for building your application. Find one that suits your style and needs and follow the examples and documentation. Most have a large library of community code you can add in with little effort, avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see in your code in **block 3**. I found the paramater `id` wasn't bound yet.

So, bind the parameter before executing if it may help you:

```
$datasend->bindParam(':id', $id);
$datasend->execute();


<?php
....................
$inputquery = "UPDATE users SET quote = :quote, WHERE id = :id";
$datasend = $connection->prepare($inputquery);
$datasend->bindParam(':id', $id);
$datasend->execute();
....................
?>
```

**EDIT & UPDATE:**

Place the session_start in the very above, as in:

```
<?php

//Stars the sessions
session_start();

//Makes sure the user is trying to edit there profile
if (!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])) {                                                   
    header("Location: http://localhost/postin'/home.php");
    exit();
}

......................
-.end-
?>

<html>
.............
-.end-
```

Comment: Looks like it is bound in the `execute()` method instead?

Comment: hm, that's the method I use in all my pdo script. sorry, I can't read all your scripts. where did you get the $id ? in 'post' or 'get' method?

Comment: Binding can be done using either approach. (I am not the OP, by the way!)

Comment: Oops, okay, where did you get $id as in, $sessionquery = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = :id"; ?

Comment: Hi :) Still +1, but it did not work on the issue :( If a user deletes there input it still fills it back in, but then if you delete it for a second time, the input is gone completely then.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you mean, I just asked you where did you get the $id ? do you get it from url parameter '($_get)' or '$_Post'. if you get the param $id from url param, then you should use only $id not $quote in Array.

Comment: Ok :) I will write an example :) Help if you would like. Ok so lets say the user enters "I like candy" for there quote. Then they completely delete the part that says "I like candy" and then there quote box is empty. So therefor once the page is reloaded (from the form submit button), the quote box should be empty. Yet it is NOT :( It is filled in with the thing the user deleted, but then if it is deleted a SECOND time it is then gone. Yet the problem is it is not deleted the first time, and I do not know why :( I am pretty sure the database is not updating the variables at the right time.

Comment: then it's a matter of session :D, I mean the problem is in '$_SESSION'

Comment: Hmm, I do not think so :( The session only stores the ID, not anything else. I think that the first time the user clicks input with the empty input it reloads the page. Then it updates to the database, and after that it re-sets the variables. That is when the inputs are blank, so I think it is a matter of adding the database entry  and resetting the variables someone wheres else in the code. Yet I do not know where that is, I have tried adding the reset variables part and the update database part twice in the form, but that did not seem to work. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70608/discussion-between-jean-gkol-and-michael-jones).

Comment: @michaeljones: when you do that first submit (the one that appears to fail to do a database update) have you independently checked that the database was or was not updated? Use either the MySQL console, or a client access program like phpMyAdmin or MySQL WorkBench.

Comment: @halfer, thank you for helping me! :) Ok I have done TONS of more testing, and here is what I have found out. First off once I am updating to the database, and then print the information from the database right below that it has the correct information. Yet if I print the information from the database once the page has reloaded, the information is OLD :( So then the page requires one additional refresh (or button submit), and then the information is the updated stuff.

Comment: @michaeljones: Ah, I think it is updating every time you visit the page, even when you are not submitting the form. Try wrapping the update code with a `if ($_POST) {` block wrapped around it.

Comment: Ok TY let me try it one second! :)

Comment: Ok, I tested this: if ($_POST) { if ($usernameinput....) { UPDATE HERE }} and it is still not working :( The inputs still like to re-input them selves (even when they are deleted). I think it just does not have the updated information, but I do now know how to fix this?

Comment: so sorry I'm in my duty now, okay I must grab the codes and try in my site first ..

Comment: SO you can help later? :)

Comment: now, I'm working with your code, but please don't check solved first .. pls. I haven't done with your code and unsolved, right? pls

Comment: I'll post after checking in : Discussion in Chat.

Comment: @halfer, if you make any more updates please post here with Jean Gkol and I if you can :) http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70608/discussion-between-jean-gkol-and-michael-jones

Comment: @Jean Gkol, I fixed the issue, THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!! :D I could not figure it out, so I looked at what you posted again, and it completely fixed it! :) THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! :D :D :D BTW I used the Meta thing

Comment: thanks God. I'm happy you can get it solved. you know? I'm even confused my own solution I gave you. what's wrong with "me" (not the problem") Lolz .. success for you friend :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to pin down your immediate problem, as you have posted a lot of code. So, I'll add another thing to fix, in case it helps.

Don't do this:

```
include("C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\header.php");
```

Firstly, the brackets are unnecessary in most cases (unless you need a return value, and you don't here), so it now becomes:

```
include "C:\wamp\www\postin'\includes\header.php";
```

Now, it is good practice not to hardwire your full directory paths, so change it again to something like this (if you do several, just have one `$root`):

```
$root = __DIR__;
include $root . "\postin'\includes\header.php";
```

Also, whilst this will work on Windows, you may run into trouble with escape characters of special meaning, e.g. "\n" for newline). So, use forward slashes, which happily will make this work on Windows, OS X and Linux too. PHP will do the necessary conversion to backslashes:

```
$root = __DIR__;
include $root . "/postin'/includes/header.php";
```

I would say that `postin'` apostrophe is asking for trouble as well (though again it may not be the cause of your immediate problems). If you really need non-standard URL characters of that kind, I would use URL rewriting.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the helpful tips! :) But that sadly will not fix the issue :( For some reason the database is not updating :(